# How do you send a variable when including a php via shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, include, shortcode

I am including a PHP file on a WordPress page like this: `[include filepath='/my_file.php']`
The part of the `functions.php` that I changed to make it possible looks like this:

```
function include_file($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array('filepath' => NULL), $atts));
    if ($filepath!='NULL' && file_exists( trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . $filepath)){
    ob_start();
    include(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $filepath);
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return $content;
    }
}
```

However, I want to be able to send a variable with the include. It is not possible like this: `[include filepath='/my_file.php?var=1']`, but maybe you get the idea.

Right now, I created a lot of different .php files which have the variables in them and included them like this:
`[include filepath='/my_file1.php'][include filepath='/my_file2.php']`
This is really annoying to deal with and if I change something in the original php, every other one has to be changed. Is there a better way? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a variable before an include statement and that will be visible to the file you are including.

Simple example (I want to pass `$foo` into my file):

inc.php:

```
echo "inside inc.php '" . $foo . "' << ...\n";
```

test.php:

```
function hello()
{
    $foo = 9999;
    include('inc.php');
}

hello();
```

which will output:

```
# php test.php
inside inc.php '9999' << ...
```

hope that helps.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Now I created a different function for every variable in the functions.php, but I can use the same php file for every wordpress page, which was what I wanted.